# How to limit amount of UDP packets being queued

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I have a php scrip that sends a UDP packet every second to my sever.

And a C# program that listens to UDP packets and then shows them using a datagridview.
To do this I spawn two threads one to listen all the time and another to process the data. They use ConcurrentQueue, the listen method enqueue the data and the processor method dequeue it and show it parsed on the datagridview.

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        threadUdp = new Thread(Listener);
        threadUdp.Start();

        threadProcessor = new Thread(startPacketProcessor);
        threadProcessor.Start();

        this.btnStart.Enabled = false;

    }
    void Listener()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            receivedBytes = listener.Receive(ref sender);
            Packet packetData = new Packet(sender, receiver, receivedBytes);
            _queue.Enqueue(packetData);
        }
    }

    private void startPacketProcessor()
    {
        int i = 0;
        Packet packet;
        while (true)
        {
            var ok = _queue.TryDequeue(out packet);
            if (ok)
            {
                string data = GetHexStringFrom(packet.ReceivedBytes);

                string[] row = new string[] { System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), packet.FIP, packet.FPort, packet.TIP, packet.TPort, data, "", i++.ToString() };

                this.dataGridViewPackets.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.dataGridViewPackets.Rows.Add(row); });

                if (this.dataGridViewPackets.RowCount >= 100)
                {
                    this.dataGridViewPackets.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.dataGridViewPackets.Rows.RemoveAt(0); });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I noticed that this programs keeps adding packets to the datagridview long after the php script stops executing, even if I stop the c# debugging and then start the program again new data is kept being added to the datagridview without executing the php script again...

I'm worried this could cause a memory leak somewhere and I don't know why this is happening...
Could it be that I'm reading data faster then I can process it and the ConcurrentQueue stores it even after I stop the debugger? If so how can I limit the amount of objects the ConcurrentQueue can store before losing information? If I don't limit it will it cause a memory leak if enough packets are queued?
Or could it be that the OS queues the UDP packets and if so, how do I check how many packets are queued by the OS?

Comment: @itsme86 Using TCP is not an option in this case. I must use UDP, so I need to understand how the  ConcurrentQueue or the OS stores the UDP packets if they are not being read or processed fast enough.

Comment: _"then start the program again new data is kept being added to the datagridview without executing the php script again"_ -- this proves that the UDP datagrams sent earlier by the PHP script are being buffered somewhere prior to arriving in your program. This makes your question fundamentally _not_ a programming question, but instead a network configuration and management question. I'm a bit surprised a the behavior, since usually a flood of UDP datagrams results in a bunch being dropped, not in them being buffered for some extended period of time ...

Comment: ... (e.g. long enough to close a program and start it again). But, there's nothing in network specifications that _forbids_ such behavior. Note that if the datagrams are being buffered before arriving at your program, it's _possible_ your code's throughput is not being tested. It depends on why the buffering is happening. If your code is the bottleneck, then you're not receiving datagrams quickly enough. But it could also be some other link in the delivery route that's not keeping up.